# Receive input from method using File IO (Java)

Tags: java, oop, io

I need to allow the user to tell the program where the file is and output that data in a particular way. I cannot seem to pass the data to the separate class file. What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class Student_Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // sets up scanner
    System.out.print("Enter file name: "); //user provides file name and location
    String userFile = in.nextLine(); // accepts input from user
    File file = new File(userFile); //uses the file method to import the data
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file); // uses scanner to read the data
    System.out.print(inputFile.Out());



}

}
```

Also can I have some tips on how to start a separate Student class to do the work. The file that I'll be reading in has multiple lines of text. I will have to take some of that text and convert it into integers. Then I have to output it in a certain way. Should I use a void method or a return method?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few tips
First you have to think what attributes a Student class needs.For example:
A student has a full name ,a social security number (maybe?)
Then you can create something like this as a seperate class

```
public class Student {
    private String fullName,socialSecurityNumber;
    public Student(String fullname,String secNumb){
        fullName=fullname;
        socialSecurityNumber=secNumb;
    }
}
```

But mostly you have to think of what the student class has to do .

Comment: The student class will be given a text file with the number of students, the name of each student and 3 scores for each student. `<no of students>` `<student name>` `<score 1>` `<score 2>` `<score 3>` ... with each element in its own row.

Comment: Maybe rename the student class to Classroom.At least this is what makes sense for me.A classroom has students and a Student has  a name and some scores

Answer (score 0):

I've just been working a bit with file processing myself. Still learning the basic concepts of java and to my level I found this tutorial quite helpful: http://www.functionx.com/java/Lesson23.htm. 
It goes through how you create, save, open and read from a file.

As seen in the tutorial one way to output the contents of your file would be to save each line to a variable. Assuming that you know what information is placed on each line this will give you some flexibility in regard to how you want to present the file contents. You can use the `nextLine()` for that as well. You can do this in a while loop, which reads every line in the file.

```
while(inputFile.hasNext()){
String studentName = inputFile.nextLine();
String studentCourse = inputFile.nextLine();
}
```

The `hasNext()` returns true until the Scanner gets to the end of the file and there are no more lines to read.

If you want to print your file contents to the console you can probably then use a void method as it doesn't require you to return anything.